# d3js Tree Change Text Style OnClick

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a d3js tree chart, and want to change the events that happen when a user expands the tree. I want the user to expand the tree by clicking on the circle but create an onclick when the user clicks the text. I update the state of each node to Session which then use to create the json data.

I have two elements in my json data 'Expanded' and 'Selected' which I use to display the state of the chart showing which nodes have been expanded and change the text style to show which have been selected.

I want to be able to change the text style when the user clicks on the text link and not the circle to update the live chart without having to doa post back from the saved data. This onclick will also send the 'selected' status of the node to my be saved in a session.

```
 function update(source) {
    var duration = d3.event && d3.event.altKey ? 5000 : 500;

    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function (d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function (d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
        //  Node On Click Event to update selected record to list
        .on("click", function (d) {
            toggle(d); update(d);
            // Try and add Selected node to Company Select Matrix Model Binder
        AddRemoveContexttoModelBinder(d);
    });

    nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6)
        .style("fill", function (d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; })
        .style("fill", function (d) { return d.free ? "red" : "black"});


    nodeEnter.append("a")
        .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
            return d.url;
        })
        .append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
        //      .style('fill', function (d) {
        //          return d.free ? 'black' : '#999';
        //      })
        .style('fill', function(d) {
            return d.nonselectable ? 'red' : '#999';
        })
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);


    nodeEnter.append("svg:title")
      .text(function (d) {
          return d.description;
          // Append details to each node if they have been selected});

    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });
    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 4.5)
        .style("fill", function (d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; })
        .style("fill", function (d) { return d.selected ? "green" : "yellow"});

    nodeUpdate.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            if (d.nonselectable) {
                return "red";
            } else {
                return d.selected ? "green" : "black";
            }
        })
        .style("fill-opacity", function (d) { return d.nonselectable ? .5 : 1 });

        // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
        .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6);

    nodeExit.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Update the links…
    var link = vis.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(tree.links(nodes), function (d) { return d.target.id; });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("svg:path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function (d) {
            var o = { x: source.x0, y: source.y0 };
            return diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
        })
      .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function (d) {
            var o = { x: source.x, y: source.y };
            return diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
        })
        .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function (d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });
}
```

Update:
I have created a jsfiddle page with some test case data, http://jsfiddle.net/mrchrispaton/aut40rk2/10

Comment: Can you make a much smaller test case to demonstrate what you want accomplished?

Comment: There area four levels in the tree, of Group, Company, Contractor and Site. The json data has an option for expanded and selected. The expanded option saves the view state of the chart to determine what is displayed when the chart is displayed on load/re opening page. The selected option is what I wish to use to save when the user clicks on the 'Text'. So i want to use the circle to expand the tree but use the text to select the node. I am using a ajax to save the data to my MVC action but wish to update the changes in the tree as the user clicks the text. Test data now in jsfiddle, Thanks